# C++: sizeof of struct with bit fields

Tags: c++, sizeof

Why is gcc giving returning 13 as the sizeof of the following class ?
It seems to me that we should get e (4 bytes) + d (4 bytes) + 1 byte (for a and b) = 9 bytes. If it was alignment, aren't most 32 bit systems aligned on 8 byte boundaries ?

```
class A {
  unsigned char a:1;
  unsigned char b:4;
  unsigned int d;
  A* e;
} __attribute__((__packed__));


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  cout << sizeof(A) << endl;
}
```

./a.out
13

Comment: I would guess 32 bit systems would actually be aligned on 4 byte (32 bits) boundaries.

Comment: Also note: http://digitalvampire.org/blog/index.php/2006/07/31/why-you-shouldnt-use-__attribute__packed/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are very likely running on a 64 bit platform and the size of the pointer is not 4 but 8 bytes. Just do a sizeof on A * and print it out.

Answer (score 6):

The actual size of structs with bitfields is implementation dependent, so whatever size gcc decides it to be would be right.

Comment: This is correct, but I don't see any reason why it would allocate 5 bytes for 5 bits (unless its really stupid compiler without any internal bit-wise operations).

Comment: Yes, its a bit strange that it allocates an odd number of bytes. However, it can do it if it wants too, which is a strong hint that another method should be used in order to control the number of bytes allocated.

Comment: +1 - Right answer. If you want to be able to specify exactly which bytes get which data in a struct and what its ultimate size is, you'd be better off using Ada.